# Convergence in Riemann Sphere iff convergence in Complex plane

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am reading Complex Analysis from Conway and came across this assertion:

> A sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $\mathbf{C}$ converges to some $z$ in $\mathbf{C}$ if and only if $z_n \to z$ in $\mathbf{C_{\infty}}$.

Recall that the metric on $\mathbf{C_{\infty}}$ is $d(z,w)=\frac{2|z-w|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1+|w|^2}}$ for $z,w \in \mathbf{C}$.

One direction is straightforward: If $z_n \to z$ in $\mathbf{C}$, then $d(z_n,z) \leq 2|z_n-z| \to 0.$

But how do I show the reverse direction? Can I say $z_n$ must be bounded in absolute value if it converges in the metric $(\mathbf{C_{\infty}},d)$?

Comment: Are you sure about this? What about the sequence $z_n = n$? Surely this converges to $\infty$ in $\mathbf C_\infty$, but doesn't converge in $\mathbf C$?

Comment: @KennyWong Both the sequence $z_n$ and limit $z$ are assumed to be in $\mathbf{C}$. So, the limit point $z=\infty$ is not a counterexample.